# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL update..) where `id` is null)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have some code producing the following error. How can I fix it?

BookController

```
public function bookedit(Request $req,$id){
    $this->middleware('admin');
    $edit = Book::where('bookID','=',$id)->first();
    $edit->bookName = $req->input('bookName');
    $edit->author = $req->input('author');
    $edit->categoryID = $req->input('categoryID');
    $edit->nxb = $req->input('nxb');
    $edit->description = $req->input('description');
    $edit->price = $req->input('price');
    $edit->update();
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg', 'Sua thanh cong']);
}
```

Of course my primary key in Book.php is **bookID** not **id**
so why do **id** column appear here???

Comment: Does it work if you change `$edit->update()` to `$edit->save()`?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration

Comment: Do you mean `protected $primaryKey = 'bookID';`? Also, consider deleting/self-answering your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `Book` model define

```
class Book extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'bookID';
    ......
}
```